# Tags don't always appear to be vertically aligned (Android App)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

It looks like tags which don't have letters that go below the "line" appear to be aligned vertically slightly higher then tags with words that have letters that go below the "line".

Nexus 5, android 4.4.2

[image: a screenshot that has tags]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have eyes like a hawk! This has been fixed for version 0.1.89 coming out around midnight UTC.

I'd also like to thank you since the comments I wrote in the code about this bug fix required me to spend some time learning the differences between baseline, descending lines, and ascending lines so I could use the correct terms, which was fun.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the actual terminology!